# iOS Conversion from a dictionary to a NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary holding EXIF metadata from a picture.
An example:

```
const CFStringRef kCGImagePropertyExifExposureTime;
```

Instead of accessing every key individually, I just want write the whole dictionary content into a label.
When I want to write this data into the console I would just use:

```
NSLog(@"EXIF Dic Properties: %@",EXIFDictionary );
```

That works fine, but if I use:

```
NSString *EXIFString = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary)];
```

I get warnings that the result is not a string literally and if I try to use that string to set my label.text, the program crashes.

Any idea where my error is?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis, they are unnecessary, and are confusing both the compiler, and the va_args stuff going on behind the scenes in NSString.  When you write out an NSLog, the string is only in parenthesis because it is being passed as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary)]` is not, as you may think, a method with two arguments. It's a method with one argument. That one argument is `(@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary)`, which uses the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and ends up returning `EXIFDictionary`. So in essence you have

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:EXIFDictionary]
```

which is obviously wrong. This is also why you're getting a warning. That warning tells you that the format argument is not a string literal, because using variables as format strings is a common source of bugs. But more importantly here, that argument isn't even a string at all, and so it crashes.

Remove the parentheses and everything will be fine. That will look like

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary];
```

Answer (score 3):

> I get warnings that the result is not a string literally

Nah. You get a warning saying that the format string of `stringWithFormat:` is not a string *literal.* That's because you don't know how the comma operator (and a variadic function) works (that's why one should master the C language before trying to make an iOS app). Basically what you have here:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:(@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary)]
```

is, due the behavior of the comma operator, is equivalent to

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:EXIFDictionary]
```

which is obviously wrong. Omit the parentheses, and it will be fine:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want those parentheses:

```
NSString *EXIFString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"EXIF Properties: %@", EXIFDictionary];
```